# where are the definitions for the cout, cin objects placed?

Tags: c++, namespaces, iostream

Are they in the namespace std? or in the header file ?
I have heard that  only contains the prototype of functions and not the definitions. Am I right?

Comment: They aren't functions, they're objects.

Comment: Look for the C++ standard library source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cout` and `cin` (and `cerr` as well) are namespace-scope objects (not functions) in namespace `std`. They're declared in the header `<iostream>`. Their definition is technically an implementation detail — in practice, it is most likely in the C++ runtime library.

Comment: Also, their types are defined in the header.